# iOS 7: Proper iPad icons for iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios7

We have an app for iPhone only, but often users install it on their iPads. With iOS7 and the asset groups, it no longer respects our new iPad icon image sizes (76px and 152px). If we don't use asset groups and have our old icons (72px), it will load them, but they clearly look scaled. If we rename our 76px to Icon-72 and Icon-72@2x, the same problem happens.

Is there a proper way to get iOS 7 sized iPad icons in an iPhone only app?

Thanks!

Comment: Must we manually prepare icons of all sizes, and match the required sizes precisely?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Took me a while to work this one out, as I was having the same issue.

If you highlight your AppIcon Asset group when looking at it in Xcode, you can add additional fields to it by opening the inspector (right hand pane) and clicking the checkboxes on what you want. Then you can drag in your icons and have them work properly.

Answer (score 7):

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1686/_index.html) the guidelines iOS for all icons and the new guidelines for iOS 7 [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html).

and [Here](http://makeappicon.com/) a website to create all size of your icons for iOS 6, 7 and Android with the 1024*1024.

Add the different keys of your icon in your `info.plist` and add the icons in your resources :

[image]

[image]

Comment: what size is icon.png?

Comment: `> i0S 7` it's `Icon-60@2x.png` and the size is `120x120`. For `iOS 6 and earlier` it's `Icon.png` `Icon@2x.png` and the size are `57x57` and `114x114`