# Changing app icons, missing an icon somehwere

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

So my design guy asked to change our app icon. I thought I replaced them all, but when I build, I seem to be missing one.

After archive, Organizer is missing the icon:

[image]

I thought I added them all.

Target Build settings:
[image]

plist:

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: you've tried to restart Xcode?

Comment: Have a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19312080/ios-7-proper-ipad-icons-for-iphone-app/19312975#19312975

Comment: @MirkoCatalano restarted Xcode, still have issue.

Comment: you have add the icons in itunesConnet?

Comment: @MirkoCatalano Yes I have.

Comment: I renamed the icon files and it is working now, thanks @JordanMontel for the link.

Comment: asd i look just now the name of your icon

Comment: @Log139 you'r welcome :) don't hesitate to upvote