# iCon file is missing when upload to App Store

Tags: icons, app-store, ios7, plist

When i upload my iPad app for iOS7 to app store , i got following message.

[image]

And here is my plist file.

[image]

I don't know where am i wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your way to add icons on your project. You can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19312080/ios-7-proper-ipad-icons-for-iphone-app/19312975#19312975).
But, in your case, you have a problem with the name.
Your icon is named `iCons` and the @2x named `iCon@2x` without S and verify if you have all your icons file in your resources.

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1686/_index.html) the guidelines iOS for all icons and the new guidelines for iOS 7 [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html).

and [Here](http://makeappicon.com/) a website to create all size of your icons for iOS 6, 7 and Android with the 1024*1024.

Add the different keys of your icon in your `info.plist` and add the icons in your resources :

[image]

[image]

Comment: no. That is not me, i always upvote everyone who answer my question . even it's not help. Now i upvoted your post.

Comment: I don't accuse you :) I ask the downvoter to explain me why :)
Did you try one solution of the two answers ?

Comment: yes bro. i got it now. icon file name is missing. :D btw i thinks that your itunesArtwork should not png file bro.Is that right?

Comment: Maybe, but it's work with .png (without the extension is hidden so..) Enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

Under App icons category under general section , select correct image like this. see screen shot.

[image]