# Are icon names important for app submission on iOS 7

Tags: ios7, icons, app-store

I am a litte confused. There are a lot of different size of icons and I can't find how can I name them. Can I give them random names?

[image]

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19376962/icon-file-is-missing-when-upload-to-app-store/19377159#19377159

Comment: thank you very much.. I found this great tool. http://makeappicon.com

Comment: Yep :) Could you validate the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1686/_index.html) the guidelines iOS for all icons and the new guidelines for iOS 7 [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html).

and [Here](http://makeappicon.com/) a website to create all size of your icons for iOS 6, 7 and Android with the 1024*1024.

Add the different keys of your icon in your `info.plist` and add the icons in your resources :

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can give iOS app icons arbitrary names (ending in .png).  They don't need to be named Icon-xyz.png.  But you might want to use a clear obvious descriptive naming scheme anyway, so that you can keep them straight, non-duplicated, and easily check for missing sizes in the project file directory and app plist.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [iOS Developer Library article](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1686/_index.html) that Jordan linked, almost all don't require a specific filename:

> Prior to iOS 3.2, icon images were required to follow a strict naming convention. ... Except for iTunesArtwork, icon images included in your app can have arbitrary names.

It also interestingly notes the following:

> iTunesArtwork icon images should be in png format, but name them without the .png extension.