# iOS AppStore icon naming

Tags: ios7, icons

I'm a little bit confused about the App Icon for the App Store which is supposed to be required ([link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html)).[image]

What is the naming convention for the new App Icon for the App Store? I can't find any information about that.

Before iOS7 there was an non-required image with the same size with the naming convention `iTunesArtwork@2x`. Is it the same?

Comment: Have a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19312080/ios-7-proper-ipad-icons-for-iphone-app/19312975#19312975

Comment: Thanks! Helped me a lot. I'm supprized that there is no straight Apple source with all necessary information for iOS7.