# Blank app icon on iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I have an **iPhone only(not universal)** app which uses asset catalogs to config app icons. Because it's an iPhone only app, I did't config any iPad icon.

[image]

However, when I install my app on an iPad, the icon and the launch image go blank.

Does this mean that I should use old style naming convention instead of asset catalogs, or I should fill all icons including that of iPad?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS 7: Proper iPad icons for iPhone app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19312080/ios-7-proper-ipad-icons-for-iphone-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add icons for iPad as well.